# What parts of the brain are involved in regulating blood pressure in mammals?

Tags: human-biology, circulatory-system

I'm reading this [Wikipedia  article on blood pressure and its regulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_pressure#Physiology), and it mentions that medulla is involved. however, I vaguely remember reading another article on Wikipedia and it mentioned that hypothalamus or hippocampus could be involved. So my question is - what other parts of the brain or neurotransmitters have significant effect on blood pressure regulation?

Comment: You may want to look at [vasopressin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vasopressin)

Comment: Thanks, vasopressin does appear to affect blood pressure a bit in healthy individuals. There is a duplicate mention of blood pressure in the part of the article that deals with nervous system, but I'm not sure if this is the same or different effect